# unexpected snippets behavior in vscode+latex workshop

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, vscode-snippets

I'm using vscode with the latex workshop extension, and I put the following in my latex.json file.

```
    "newcommand": {
        "prefix": "nc",
        "body": [
            "\\newcommand{\\$1}{$2}",
        ],
    },
```

I expected `nc` to expand to `\newcommand{\}{}`, with placeholders after the backslash and in the second pair of braces. However, I'm getting `\newcommand{$1}{}` with only one placeholder in the second pair of braces. Why is that? How can I get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [snippet doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar)

> With \ (backslash), you can escape `$`, `}`, and `\`. Within choice elements, the backslash also escapes comma and pipe characters.

The following string is passed to the snippet engine: `\newcommand{\$1}{$2}`

`\$` is interpreted as a literal `$`

We want the following string to be passed : `\newcommand{\\$1}{$2}`

Escaping this string for json gives

```
"\\newcommand{\\\\$1}{$2}"
```

Comment: so the backslashes are handled in two passes? first by json, and then by the snippet engine?

Comment: and why can the backslash only escape closing braces, not opening ones?

Comment: @user313032 they probably don't have a problem with `{` when it is used in a placeholder